# Common expression for "we haven't been spending much time together"?

Tags: expressions

Like a couple not spending much time together. The only thing I could come out with is "we've been a little apart," though I'm not totally sure whether it is common or not.

Other suggestions?

Comment: Long time no see!

Answer (score 4):

You could say

> "There seems to be an unusual distance between us."

Or,

> "We seem to be drifting apart."

Or,

> "We seem to be looking for excuses not to get together."

Or,

> "Our times together seem to be few and far between lately."  (Note:  To be correct, to a ridiculous extreme, a better wording would be, "Our times together seem to be fewer and further between lately.")

Or,

> "Our *tête-à-tête* are less frequent of late.

Comment: @janoChen:  That's good.  You know what they say:  "Laughter is the best medicine."